# Disks 20.04 Seagate SSHD Error

Tags: hard-drive, 20.04

I have a 4 and a half year old PC running Ubuntu 20.04 with a Seagate SSHD (hybrid drive) 2tb. Over the last month sometimes I start it up to a flashing cursor (happens more often since 20.04). I just restart and it works fine. Today I started and got disk_error. restarted and it worked fine. However I want to get to the cause of this. Is the HDD developing a fault? Output from disks below, I don't know if this is good or bad output. I've opened the PC up and checked all cables etc are secure. When the PC does start it works fine (it boots up fine 90% of the time).

I don't know if I should leave it as it is, replace the HDD or whether it might be a software issue?

[[image: 20.04 Disks output1]

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with Seagate SSHD, mine is a little older SSHD drive, the problem seems to be bad firmware from seagate, the MLC or TLC cells used for solid state drive memory seems to get corrupted and the firmware keeps copying to it, giving all kind of SMART drive errors, it should avoid bad cells and use the magnetic disk only but it seems not to be doing this, I have used it as an external drive connected to and USB 3 (because it uses more than 2.5 Watts) port and everything runs well somehow, maybe it avoids flash memory when being used as USB or the SMART errors just don't show error messages when running on USB external port, but as soon as I use it as internal SATA all the errors POP up, even if it works ok, I am using it on an old computer and saving to it not very important media, I wonder how much time it will work, as it's being like this for years already...